# How do I get the logged-in User ID when creating a post request for that user without using req.params.id?

Tags: node.js, express, post, mongoose

Let's say I have an API with a /posts endpoint. Each post in my Mongoose schema has a reference to the user that created it, and each user has an array of references to the posts they created.

When posting as a logged-in user, in order to save that reference I need to send the current logged-in user ID along with the content of the post to the /posts endpoint. I would prefer not to do so through some nested query like /users/:id/posts and then send req.params.id. I would like to post directly to /posts but send the user.id in the request somehow.

User model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  posts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }]
});
```

Posts model:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

Create new post (need a way to get the user ID since it won't actually be in req.params)

```
exports.createPost = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { content } = req.body; // ideally would get user ID from here
    const post = await db.Post.create({
      content,
      user: req.params.id
    });
    const postUser = await db.User.findById(req.params.id);
    postUser.posts.push(post.id);
    await postUser.save();
    const newPost = await db.Post.findById(post.id); 
    const {id, created} = newPost;
    return res.status(201).json({
      id,
      content,
      created
    })
  }
  catch(err) {
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

I know I'm probably missing something obvious, but I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please share your some code

Comment: @KingStone Added